# Comparing lists in JUnit. It succeeds but I have not override equals. How does it work?

Tags: java, unit-testing, list, collections, junit

I have a class with primitive fields like the following:

```
public class Person{  
  String name;  
  int age;  
  int id;  
  int height;  
  public Person(String name, int age, int id, int height){  
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;  
      this.id = id;  
      this.height = height;  
  } 
  //other methods
}
```

I have various persons that I want to sort by age:

```
Person p87 = new Person("John", 87, 123, 185);  
Person p22 = new Person("George", 22, 12, 180);  
//etc  ....for other persons. Then I create a list of them
List<Person> persons= Arrays.asList(p87, p22, p45, p31, p55, p62 );  
Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Person p1, person p2) {
                return p1.age - p2.age;
            }

        });
```

Now I want to test if it has been sorted correctly so I have a JUnit test case with the following:

`assertEquals(Arrays.asList(p22, p31, p45, p55, p62, p87 ), persons);`

The testcase passes. So it is sorted.
But I don't understand this. The `assertEquals` would compare the 2 lists using the [List.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) which calls the `equals` *on each contained object*.
The problem is that I have not override `equals` in the class `Person`.
As a result the following **fails**:

```
Person p22 = new Person("George", 22, 12, 180);   
Person p22_2 = new Person("George", 22, 12, 180);    
assertEquals(p22, p22_2);
```

I don't understand this. Why then the 2 list passed as equal in the test case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example you aren't creating *new* objects - you are comparing references to the *same* object. This works because the default implementation of `equals` is to compare for reference equality.

You are doing the equivalent of this:

```
Person p22 = new Person("George", 22, 12, 180);   
Person p22_2 = p22;
assertEquals(p22, p22_2);   // works, because both refer to the same object
```

Comment: So you are saying that `Arrays.asList(p22, p31, p45, p55, p62, p87 )` makes a list with the same references in the same positions after the `persons` list has been sorted? Now I am confused. Should I consider the testcase as pass or should I be overriding `equals` in `Person` and create new list?

Comment: @user384706: `should I ... create new list`. It has nothing to do with the list. List overrides equals. `should I be overriding equals in Person` That depends on whether you want two objects with the same values to compare equal. Usually you do want that (but not always). `Should I consider the testcase as pass` If you are testing the sorting - yes, it worked. If you want to test that `equals` works in the way you want then write a new test for that. Test only one thing per test.

Comment: Yes.I am only interested if the sorting worked.So it is a pass because the same elements as before (from the point of memory areas) are in the correct positions after the `Collections.sort`. Right?

Comment: @user384706: I wouldn't think of it as "memory areas" if I were you - it's not a good analogy for references. There's no guarantee that the objects are in the same position in memory before and after the sorting (in particular the garbage collector can move objects in memory whenever it wants to). You should think of references as some opaque value that uniquely identifies each object, but the actual numerical value is not visible to you. If you have two references you can ask if they point to the same object or not, but you can't ask where that object is in memory.